# Ripple out integer array optimisation in Java

Tags: java, arrays, optimization

I am trying to write a function that will accept an array length, and return a "ripple out" array.

For example:
`rippleOut(3)` would return `[0,1,0]`
`rippleOut(6)` would return `[0,1,2,2,1,0]`

This is what I've got so far. It works, but I'm sure that there is a more efficient way to do it:

```
public int[] rippleOut(int size){
    int[] output = new int[size];
    int middle = 0;
    boolean even = false;

    if(size%2==0){
        middle = (size/2-1);
        even = true;
    } else {
        middle = (int)Math.floor(size/2);
    }

    for(int i = middle; i>0; i--){
        output[i] = middle - (middle-i);
        if (even){
            output[middle+(middle - i+1)] = middle - (middle-i);
        } else {
            output[middle+(middle - i)] = middle - (middle-i);
        }

    }

    return output;
}
```

Comment: Well, there are some odd things going on. For example, you take the `floor` of an integer, and `middle - (middle-i)` is more commonly written as just `i`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a Java 8 version:

```
int size = 11;
int odd = (size % 2 == 0) ? 0 : 1;
int mid = (size / 2) - 1;
int[] output = IntStream.range(0, size - 1)
         .map(i -> (i > mid) ? mid + (mid - i) + odd : i).toArray();

IntStream.of(output).forEach(System.out::print);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is at least a simpler way to write it, I haven't compared the performance:

```
public static int[] rippleOut(int x) {
    int[] r = new int[x];
    // everything except the middle of an odd array
    for (int i = 0; i < (x >> 1); i++) {
        r[i] = i;
        r[x - i - 1] = i;
    }
    // fix middle
    if ((x & 1) == 1)
         r[x >> 1] = x >> 1;
    return r;
}
```

Feel free to replace the bitmath with "normal" math if you're more comfortable with that, it's not integral to the solution. I just like it this way, that's all.